# Referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll and creating Cloud Blob Client using CreateCloudBlobClient() method in Runbook under Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I am trying to create a runbook in Azure Automation which will take a snapshot of the VM. I found "CreateBlobSnapshot.ps1" from script center. It works good in Power Shell. But when I try to use the same code in run book it was throwing couple of exceptions.

Example: 
A. method invocation is not supported in a windows powershell workflow ..... and B. It was not able to locate Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll. I tried writing InlineScript too without luck. Please advice.

```
#Loading Windows Azure Storage Library for .NET.
Write-Verbose-Message"Loading Windows Azure Storage Library from $StorageLibraryPath"
Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$StorageLibraryPath") | Out-Null

$Creds=New-ObjectMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("$StorageAccountName","$StorageAccountKey")
$CloudStorageAccount=New-ObjectMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount($creds, $true)
$CloudBlobClient=$CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
```

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45251bdb-bb20-488c-a428-3ee1094fd568/referencing-microsoftwindowsazurestoragedll-and-creating-cloud-blob-client-using?forum=azureautomation

Answer (score 2):

For issue B, did all the Dependent DLL got loaded as well? Try this  [To Load Windows Storage Dll](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

```
PM> Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
```

Then trying loading the DLL in PowerShell using:

```
PM> Add-Type -Path "<Path where package is present>\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
```